# Why does free work like this?

Tags: c, malloc, ansi-c

Given the following code:

```
typedef struct Tokens {
    char **data;
    size_t count;
} Tokens;

void freeTokens(Tokens *tokens) {
    int d;
    for(d = 0;d < tokens->count;d++)
        free(tokens->data[d]);
    free(tokens->data);
    free(tokens);
    tokens = NULL;
}
```

Why do I need that extra:

```
free(tokens->data);
```

Shouldn't that be handled in the for loop?

I've tested both against valgrind/drmemory and indeed the top loop correctly deallocates all dynamic memory, however if I remove the identified line I leak memory.

Howcome?

Comment: No, `tokens->data` is also dynamically allocated. You have an array of strings, so the loop frees the strings, the second free frees the array, and finally you free the struct. Note that `data` is a `char **` and not a `char * []`

Comment: You allocate a bunch of pointers and have a pointer point to them. Then you allocate a bunch of char's and have the bunch of pointers point to them.  So you must deallocate in reverse order.

Comment: I would have thought that freeTokens(myTokens) would have sufficed...
When I call malloc(sizeof(Tokens)) it both mallocs the char**data AND the pointer to myTokens?

Comment: Nope! it only allocates enough room to store the pointer `data`.

Comment: Ah! I think I get it now thanks!

Comment: You should show the corresponding calls to `malloc()`.

Comment: @DeiDei Certainly more _convenient_ to free in reverse order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at a diagram of the memory you're using in the program:

```
+---------+       +---------+---------+---------+-----+
| data    |  -->  | char *  | char *  | char *  | ... |
+---------+       +---------+---------+---------+-----+
| count   |            |         |         |
+---------+            v         v         v
                     +---+     +---+     +---+
                     | a |     | b |     | c |
                     +---+     +---+     +---+
                     |...|     |...|     |...|
                     +---+     +---+     +---+
```

In C, we can dynamically allocate space for a *group* (more simply, an array) of elements. However, we can't use an array type to reference that dynamic allocation, and instead use a pointer type. In this case, the pointer just points to the first element of the dynamically allocated array. If you add 1 to the pointer, you'll get a pointer to the second element of the dynamically allocated array, add two to get a pointer to the second element, and so on.

In C, the bracket syntax (`data[1]`) is shorthand for addition and dereferencing to a pointer. So pointers in C can be used like arrays in this way.

In the diagram, `data` pointing to the first `char *` in the dynamically allocated array, which is elsewhere in memory.

Each member of the array pointed to by `data` is a string, itself dynamically allocated (since the elements are `char *`s).

So, the loop deallocates the strings (`'a...'`, `'b...'`, `'c...'`, etc), `free(tokens->data)` deallocates the array `data` points to, and finally, `free(tokens)` frees the entire struct.

Comment: Makes total sense now! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`data` is a pointer to a pointer. This means `data` points to a dynamically allocated array of pointers, which then each point to the actual data. The first for loops frees each of the pointers IN the array, but you still need to free the original pointer TO that array of the other points which you freed already. That's the reason for the line you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, every `malloc()` should have a corresponding call to `free()`. If you look at the code which allocates the memory in this program, you will very likely see a very strict correspondence with the code you posted here that frees the memory.